# I have installed and configured Graylog 3.0 on my virtual machine CentOS7,it can be visted by IE on centos7 but on local cannot visit

Tags: linux, networking, graylog

I'v checked all necessary software `jdk, MongoDB, Elasticsearch` and are running, the port 9000 is open on CentOS. What's wrong?

Comment: do you mean you're not able to access graylog from inside the CentOS VM, using IP or localhost? Whats the error you get, try with curl from CLI as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well..It's caused by the IP conflict bewteen VM and VM8 network adapter.Reallocate,everything goes well,solved by my colleague.